# unable to post large files using spring rest template w/ custom interceptor

Tags: java, spring, large-files, resttemplate

I am trying to POST a large file from one microservice to another using spring rest template POST w/ custom interceptor as follows:

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add({customInterceptor});
MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("file", {InputStreamResource});
body.add("metadata", {JSON string});
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
restTemplate.exchange({url}, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, ...);
```

(It makes no difference whether I use a SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory or HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory)

Adding an interceptor results in the creation of an new InterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory (which wraps the original request factory) on a call to getRequestFactory.

This works fine for smaller files but for large files - since requests are never delegated to the original request factory, no streaming ever occurs and, hence, results in a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exception.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this problem of RestTemplate will not be fixed according to [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20926)

> we're not going to support this, now that the WebClient is available and provides first-class support for streaming.

Note that `WebClient` is available in Spring 5.

Answer (score 0):

I have also come across this issue, but switching to `WebClient` is not an option at this point in time so I opted for a work around by implementing a new `ClientHttpRequestFactory` (albeit via an `AbstractClientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper`); it mainly works due to the fact that we are only tweaking the headers and not the body.

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleRequestFactory =
    new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();

simpleRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(10000);
simpleRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(60000);
simpleRequestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false); // this enables streaming

SomeHeaderInterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory interceptingRequestFactory =
    new SomeHeaderInterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory(simpleRequestFactory);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(interceptingRequestFactory);
```

and this is what the `SomeHeaderInterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory` looks like:

```
public class SomeHeaderInterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory
    extends AbstractClientHttpRequestFactoryWrapper {

    // you can have fields here that are initialized in the constructor
    // e.g. a service that supplies the header value that you want to populate

    public SomeHeaderInterceptingClientHttpRequestFactory(ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory) {
        super(requestFactory);
        // initialize fields
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientHttpRequest createRequest(URI uri,
                                              HttpMethod httpMethod,
                                              ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory)
                                              throws IOException {
        ClientHttpRequest request = requestFactory.createRequest(uri, httpMethod);
        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();

        headers.set("SOME_HEADER", "some value");

        return request;
    }
}
```

If you want to do something to the body then you could also try to implement a new `ClientHttpRequest`. You will then return a new instance of your newly introduced `ClientHttpRequest` in the `createRequest` method of your newly introduced `ClientHttpRequestFactory`.